# IOError when trying to open generated file in Python

Tags: python

I am working on Spiking neural network and downloaded a benchmark from https://github.com/peter-u-diehl/stdp-mnist

I am having serious trouble running this code and I have installed the necessary things.

**See the errors generated as the codes runs**

100% complete, 0s elapsed, approximately 0s remaining.

100% complete, 0s elapsed, approximately 0s remaining.

100% complete, 0s elapsed, approximately 0s remaining.

save results

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "peterb1.py", line 516, in <module>

    np.save(data_path + 'activity/resultPopVecs' + str(num_examples), result_monitor)

  File "/srv/home/compsci/anaconda2/envs/py2b1/lib/python2.7/site-packages

/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 490, in save

    fid = open(file, "wb")

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './activity/resultPopVecs100.npy'

compsci@cclab1-5:~/Desktop/pt1$
```

**Code**

```
print ('save results')

if not test_mode:
    save_theta()
if not test_mode:
    save_connections()
else:
    np.save(data_path + 'activity/resultPopVecs' + str(num_examples), result_monitor)
    np.save(data_path + 'activity/inputNumbers' + str(num_examples), input_numbers)
```

Comment: Made title more describing of the actual error raised.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error `No such file or director: './activity/resultPopVecs100.npy` you probably generate the file path in a wrong way.

1. Confirm that there is a file called `resultPopVecs100.npy` in your `/activity` folder.
2. Generate the filepath using the `os` python library.

To get the actual system filepath to where you are running the script, use the following snippet, and then use that `BASE_DIR` to construct the rest of the path to your file.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Comment: **@Marcus Lind **thanks for your response............................................   Actually the Benchmark am using is from https://github.com/peter-u-diehl/stdp-mnist by Peter U Diehl with MNIST dataset having a training set of 60,000 examples, and a test set of 10,000 examples "http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/"  **Major issue** I want to scale down from 60,000 to 2000 training set and 10,000 to 100 test set so that my Conventional PC will run the program, **BUT** is not generating output to activity folder **How do I scale down using the code.....?** Please your support